# Applescript to send message via SMS Relay (Continuity)

Tags: applescript, osx-yosemite

Apple just releases Yosemite which allow us to send sms message (via phone) using SMS Relay (Continuity). Does anyone know how to write applescript to send sms message. (I know that we can use applescript to send imessage).

One more question that, can we use applescript to get list of message rooms or messages in a room from Message app.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162598/programmatically-send-text-message-through-messages-app-on-os-x-10-10